# How to convert in OpenERP from one chart of account to another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, accounting

I have installed *chart of accounts A* for *company1*. This chart was used couple months for accounting. How can I convert into *chart of accounts B* and keep old data for accounts (debit, credit, etc.)? In other words, is possible migrate data from one chart of accounts to another? Solution could be programmatically or trough web client interface (not important). Virtual charts of accounts can't be used. *Chart of accounts B* must became main chart with old data.

Every advice will help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to install another chart of accounts after you've run the initial configuration wizard on a new database. However, if all you want to do is change the account numbers, names, and parents to match a different chart of accounts, then you should be able to do that with a bunch of database updates. Either manually edit each account if there aren't too many accounts, or write a SQL or Python script to update all the accounts. To do that, you'll need to map each old account to a new account code, name, and parent, then use that map to generate a script.

Answer (score 0):

IMO its very difficult we are currently migrating some data and its proving to be difficult.

I would advice you to pick a date in the future and tell everyone to just use another db with the correct chart of accounts.

Your finance dept will be the one to suggest what date  is perfect. How about when a period starts.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do similar.  It is possible to massage the chart from one form to another but I found in the end that creating a New Database, bringing in modules, assigning the new Chart and then importing all critical elements was the best and safest path.

If you have a lot of transactions that will be more difficult to do the import on.  If that is the case, then massage your chart from one form to another.

I am sure there will be some way to do an active Migration sometime in the future.  You defintely don't want to live with a bad chart or with out your history if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do so is using a ETL like Talend or Pentaho (provided there is a logic as to which account will map to which other during the process). If not you will have to do so by hand.

In case there is a logic, you would export it to a format you can transform and re import. Uninstall your account chart and install the new. Then import all the data that you formatted using those tools.